# Differentiate $y = \sqrt {{{1 + 2x} \over {1 - 2x}}} $ logarithmically

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

$\eqalign{
  & y = \sqrt {{{1 + 2x} \over {1 - 2x}}}   \cr 
  & \ln y = {1 \over 2}\ln (1 + 2x) - {1 \over 2}\ln (1 - 2x)  \cr 
  & {1 \over y}{{dy} \over {dx}} = {1 \over 2} \times {2 \over {(1 + 2x)}} - {1 \over 2} \times {{ - 2} \over {(1 - 2x)}}  \cr 
  & {1 \over y}{{dy} \over {dx}} = {1 \over {(1 + 2x)}} + {1 \over {(1 - 2x)}}  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {{(1 - 2x) + (1 + 2x)} \over {(1 + 2x)(1 - 2x)}} \times y  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {{2{{(1 + 2x)}^{{1 \over 2}}}} \over {(1 + 2x)(1 - 2x){{(1 - 2x)}^{{1 \over 2}}}}}  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {2 \over {{{(1 + 2x)}^{{1 \over 2}}}{{(1 - 2x)}^{{3 \over 2}}}}} \cr} $

However the answer is:

${{dy} \over {dx}} = {2 \over {(1 - 2x)\sqrt {(1 - 4{x^2})} }}$

Where have I went wrong?

Comment: every thing is fine in last line go ahead and do  $\sqrt{1-2x}\times \sqrt{1+2x}$

Comment: where did the $y$ go in line $5$ ??

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou It was substituted by its definition (first line).

Comment: You have not gone wrong. The answer you got is perfectly correct. There is no strong argument for rewriting in the form the official answer gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{(1+2x)^\frac{1}{2}(1-2x)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{2}{(1+2x)^\frac{1}{2}(1-2x)^\frac{1}{2}(1-2x)} = \frac{2}{(1-4x^2)^\frac{1}{2}(1-2x)}$$

Comment: @Assad: Just note that $x\neq -1/2,~+1/2$.